# Why does lengthPal store the testPalindrone.length as numbers?

Tags: javascript, recursion

Trying to understand recursion, why does lengthPal store the testPalindrone.length as numbers?

When console.log is used it pushes out 5, 3, 1.
Does this mean that lengthPal is an array?

```
const checkPalindrone = (testPalindrone) => {
  let lengthPal = testPalindrone.length;
  testPalindrone = testPalindrone.toLowerCase();
  console.log(testPalindrone.length);
  console.log(typeof lengthPal);
  if (lengthPal === 0 || lengthPal === 1) {
    return true;
  }
  if (testPalindrone[0] === testPalindrone[lengthPal - 1]) {
    return checkPalindrone(testPalindrone.slice(1, lengthPal - 1));
  }
  return false;
}

console.log(checkPalindrone("Radar"));
```

Comment: `why does lengthPal store the testPalindrone.length as numbers?`, because `testPalindrone.length` returns a number!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `lengthPal` variable in the above code example is `number` (Javascript).

To help you understand the above function, let's break down the code line by line

```
let lengthPal = testPalindrone.length;
testPalindrone = testPalindrone.toLowerCase();
```

1. The `lengthPal` will get the length of the string and the `testPalindrome` will convert the input string to all lowercase.

```
if (lengthPal === 0 || lengthPal === 1) {
  return true;
}
```

2. This is the base condition of your recursion function where the computation should end once you find that the length of the input string is either 1 or 0.

```
if (testPalindrone[0] === testPalindrone[lengthPal - 1]) {
  return checkPalindrone(testPalindrone.slice(1, lengthPal - 1));
}
```

3. The above is the important step where you check if the first character (`testPalindrone[0]`) and the last character (`testPalindrone[lengthPal - 1]`) is the same. If this condition matches you basically want to reduce the string by removing the first character and the last character by doing this `testPalindrone.slice(1, lengthPal - 1)` and calling the recursive function again with the reduced string.

```
return false;
```

4. Finally, you return `false`, if the above if condition doesn't match, which in that case the string is not palindrome.

I hope this helps to understand.